# c# dotnet ef migrations script can't find project or startup-project in database-first

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-database-first, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I cannot run the following in the package manager

```
dotnet ef migrations script
```

(even if I try to add --project or --startup-project options)
I get error: No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.

Easy to demonstrate: Visual Studio/ File /New Project. Select .NET Core and Console App (.NET Core).

From Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=infostar-network;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

This builds everything: a robust context file and all the cs files for each of the tables.
Visual Studio Solution Explorer is on the base of the application (where the csproj file is located).

[image: Solution Explorer / File Manager]

I'm lost.  Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.  Chuck (Yogi)

Comment: What is your current working directory? Is the the same as where .csproj is placed?

Comment: CodeRunner: it is the application top level directory and Yes, .csproj is located there.